# Why is google chart function not being called when it's inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying to make my google chart show once they click on a tab link, but google charts doesn't show.

I included the google charts code inside `ChartlyDaily`. When it's outside the `ChartDaily` function it works , but inside it doesn't.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                function ChartDaily(){
                  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartDaily);
                  function drawChartDaily() {
                   var chart_data = ['3',7];
                   alert(chart_data);
                   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Scoring Activity', 'Points given'], chart_data]);

                   var options = {
                    title: 'Semis overall scoring activity'
                  };

                  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
              }
              jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#tabs > div').hide();
                $('#tabs div:first').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
                $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
                    $('#tabs ul li.active').removeClass('active');  // <== Only what you need
                    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    var selectedTab=$(this).attr('href');
                    $('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // <== Use a callback
                        $(selectedTab).delay(10).fadeIn('fast');          // <== add a delay
                      });        
                    return false;
                  });
                $('#menu_tab1').click(function(){
                  ChartDaily(); // supposed to show the chart
                }); 

                $('#menu_tab2').click(function(){
                 alert('tab-2 got clicked!!');

               }); 

                $('#menu_tab3').click(function(){
                 alert('tab-3 got clicked!!');

               });

                $('#menu_tab4').click(function(){
                 alert('tab-4 got clicked!!');

               });

              });

</script>

  <div id="chart_div" style=" margin-left:-280px;width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to start over from.

```
function GoogleChart() {
    this.chart_data = ['3',7];
    this.data_table = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Scoring Activity', 'Points given'], chart_data]);
    this.options = {
        title: 'Semis overall scoring activity'
    };

    this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));    
}

GoogleChart.prototype.drawChartDaily = function () {
    this.chart.draw(this.data_table, this.options);
};

$(function () {
    function myOnLoadCallback() {
        var googleChart = new GoogleChart();

        $('#menu_tab1').click(function(){
            googleChart.drawChartDaily();
        });
    }

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(myOnLoadCallback);
});
```

Edit: Changed to a non-tested example.

Comment: after what function ???? because I need to chart ChartDaily function which includes the drawchartDaily function when a tab is clicked

Comment: Sorry I'm misleading you a bit. Another problem I see that must be corrected is that google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartDaily); should only be called once.

To answer your comment question I was referring too the drawChartDaily function.

Comment: then where is my error .. How can I call the function that prints the charts on click

Answer (score 0):

The Google loader has issues being called from inside other functions, so it's best to let it run by itself.  Try something like this:

```
function ChartDaily () {
    var chart_data = ['3',7];
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Scoring Activity', 'Points given'],
        chart_data
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Semis overall scoring activity'
    };

    var chart = new oogle.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
function init () {
    $('#menu_tab1').click(function(){
        ChartDaily();
    });
}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: init});
```

Comment: How are we supposed to load google charts if we are async loading the charts script? we need to call the google.load once the script has finished loading. But for some reason the chart won't work if its inside a named function???

Comment: My knowledge of the subject is several years out of date now, but when I last used the Visualization API, the loader did not work properly when called from inside a function. I was never able to figure out why this was the case. It is entirely possible that the loader issues are fixed now, though. If they are not, I suggest opening your own question with an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The issue hasn't been fixed, I have isolated it to know that it does not work in a named function, however in an anonymous function with a setTimeout like `setTimeout(function(){google.charts.load ... etc},0)`, it does work, which is not very useful. Thanks though